# Upraded Webpack 4 to 5 : Build stalls at 10% building 0/1 entries 1/1 dependencies 0/1 modules

Tags: node.js, webpack, upgrade, babel-loader

I am upgrading my webpack from 4 to 5 , when i run webpack  command

webpack --progress --config webpack.config.js

the progress stalls at

Build stalls at 10% building 0/1 entries 1/1 dependencies 0/1 modules.

This was working fine till i was using webpack 4. I have updated the rules as per the new format for respective headers. THer is no error or warning that printed on the console. It just stalls.

Please find my package.json file

```
{  
  "name": "deploy",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
"@khanacademy/react-multi-select": "^0.3.3",
"axios": "^0.21.1",
"backbone": "1.2.3",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
"bootstrap-select": "^1.13.12",
"d3": "^3.3.11",
"eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "4.17.47",
"file-saver": "1.3.3",
"formsy-react": "0.19.5",
"globalize": "^1.4.2",
"highcharts": "^9.1.0",
"intl-tel-input": "^17.0.12",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"jquery-contextmenu": "2.7.1",
"jquery-jsonview": "1.2.3",
"jstree": "3.3.7",
"leaflet": "1.3.4",
"less": "2.3.1",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"noVNC": "git://github.com/novnc/noVNC.git#v0.6.2",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"rc-slider": "8.6.9",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-codemirror": "1.0.0",
"react-custom-scrollbars": "4.2.1",
"react-dnd": "^14.0.2",
"react-dnd-html5-backend": "^14.0.0",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-dropzone": "3.13.4",
"react-json-editor-ajrm": "^2.5.13",
"react-modal": "^3.11.2",
"react-redux": "^7.2.1",
"react-table": "^7.7.0",
"react-tabs": "^3.1.1",
"react-tag-autocomplete": "^6.1.0",
"react-tagsinput": "^3.19.0",
"react-transition-group": "1.2.0",
"react-widgets": "^4.4.11",
"react-widgets-globalize": "^5.0.20",
"react-widgets-moment": "^4.0.27",
"recharts": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-form": "^8.3.6",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"save": "^2.4.0",
"text-security": "^1.2.0",
"why-did-you-update": "^1.0.8"
},
  "browserslist": [
"defaults",
"ie >= 9",
"Firefox >= 45",
"Chrome >= 48",
"Safari >= 10"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
"@babel/cli": "7.14.3",
"@babel/core": "7.14.3",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.2.1",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.1.6",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/preset-stage-1": "7.0.0-beta.40",
"@storybook/react": "^6.2.9",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
"babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
"babel-loader": "8.2.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "1.3.5",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.0",
"cross-env": "^7.0.3",
"css-loader": "^5.2.4",
"dust-loader": "1.3.0",
"dustjs-helpers": "1.7.4",
"dustjs-linkedin": "^2.7.5",
"eslint": "^6.8.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^4.6.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
"expose-loader": "0.7.5",
"file-loader": "2.0.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"less-loader": "4.1.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "1.6.0",
"npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
"raw-text-loader": "0.1.1",
"replace-hash-in-file-webpack-plugin": "1.0.8",
"scriptjs": "2.5.9",
"style-loader": "0.23.1",
"unused-files-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
"url-loader": "1.1.2",
"webpack": "^5.38.1",
"webpack-cli": "^4.7.2"
  },
```

Here is the webpack file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ReplaceHashInFileWebpackPlugin = require('replace-hash-in-file-webpack-plugin');
const brandingDefinePlugin = require('./configs/plugins');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const config = {
entry: [
    "./src/main/webapp/app/scripts/index.js"
],
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: env !== "development" ? '[name]-[hash].js' : '[name]-dev.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test:/\.m?js$/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options:{
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                compact: false
            }
            //query: {compact: false}
        },
       {
            test: /\.dust$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "dust-loader",
                options: {
                    rootDir: './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/templates'
                }
            }]
        },
      {
            test: require.resolve('highcharts'),
            use: [{
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: 'Highcharts'
            }]
        },
        {
            test: require.resolve('underscore'),
            use: [{
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: '_'
            }]
        },
       {
            test: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/app'),
            use: [{
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: 'app'
            }]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        //importLoaders: 1,
                        sourceMap: env === 'development',
                        url: false,
                        //context: '../',
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader?name=../../images/[name].[ext]'
            }]
           
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'url-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
            }]
            //loader: 'url-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
        },
    ]
},
stats: {
    colors: true,
    errorDetails: true
},
externals: {
    'jquery': 'jQuery'
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
    descriptionFiles: ['package.json', 'bower.json'],
    alias: {
        'jquery-i18n': path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/jquery.i18n.properties-1.0.9"),
        'jquery-ui': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/jquery-ui'),
        "bootstrap-datetimepicker": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min"),
        mousewheel: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/jquery.mousewheel'),
        atmosphere: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/bower_components/jquery.atmosphere/jquery.atmosphere'),
        x2js: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/xml2json.min'),
        helpers: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/helpers'),
        jscrollpane: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/jquery.jscrollpane'),
        jqgridlocale: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/grid.locale-en'),
        'jqgrid': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/jquery.jqGrid.js'),
        idleTimer: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/idle-timer.min'),
        'jquery-tag-it': path.resolve(__dirname,'./src/main/webapp/app/bower_components/jquery-tagit/js/tag-it'),
        jsonview: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/jquery-jsonview/dist/jquery.jsonview'),
        gridster: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/bower_components/gridster/src/jquery.gridster.js'),
        'jquery-ui-multiselect-widget': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/jquery.multiselect'),
        'file-saver': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/file-saver/FileSaver.min'),
        jqueryTimeDuration: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/bower_components/jquery-time-duration-picker/src/jquery-time-duration-picker'),
        'jQuery-contextMenu': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/bower_components/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js'),
        applicationTemplates: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/applicationTemplates'),
        dust: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust'),
        'dust.core': 'dustjs-linkedin',
        'dust.parse': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/parser'),
        dustCompiler: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/compiler'),
        dustHelpers: 'dustjs-helpers',
        app: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/app'),
        routes: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/routes'),
        collections: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/collections'),
        views: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/views'),
        models: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/models'),
        schemas: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/schemas'),
        templates: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/templates'),
        controllers: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/controllers'),
        'custom-form-elements': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/helpers/custom-form-elements'),
        js: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/js'),
        bubble_chat: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/helpers/bubble_chat'),
        leaflet: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/bower_components/leaflet/leaflet'),
        MarkerCluster: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/MasterCluster-src'),
        jstree: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/jstree/dist/jstree.min'),
        geosearch: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/bower_components/L.GeoSearch/src/js/l.control.geosearch'),
        openstreetmap: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/bower_components/L.GeoSearch/src/js/l.geosearch.provider.openstreetmap'),
        googleProvider: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/bower_components/L.GeoSearch/src/js/l.geosearch.provider.google'),
        'intl-tel-input': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput-jquery.min'),
        adapter: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/adapter'),
        next: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/next'),
        spin: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/bower_components/spin/'),
        'fileSaver': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/file-saver/FileSaver'),
        'vApiClient': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/api/vApiClient'),
        vendorUtils: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/utils')
    }
},
resolveLoader: {
    alias: { "text": "raw-text-loader" }
},
mode: env,
plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        debug: false,
        options: {
            context: __dirname
        }
    }),        
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        _: 'underscore',
        dust: 'dustjs-linkedin',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        _ld:'lodash'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
        maxChunks: 1
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: env !== "development" ? 'styles/css/main-[hash].css' : 'styles/css/main-dev.css'
    }),
    new ReplaceHashInFileWebpackPlugin([{
        dir: 'build',
        files: ['index.jsp'],
        rules: [{
            search: /\/main/ig,
            replace: env !== "development" ? '/main-[hash]' : '/main-dev'
        }]
    }])
   
]
}
if (process.env.npm_config_branding === 'riverbed') {
console.log('******************** Branding : Riverbed *********************',
process.env.npm_config_branding);
console.log(JSON.stringify(brandingDefinePlugin));
config.plugins.push(brandingDefinePlugin.riverbed.oem);
} else {
console.log('******************** Branding : Versa *********************', process.env.npm_config_branding);
console.log(JSON.stringify(brandingDefinePlugin));
config.plugins.push(brandingDefinePlugin.versa.oem);
}
if (!process.env.NO_COPY) {
config.plugins.push(new CopyWebpackPlugin({patterns:[
    {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/mock/json/*.json',
        to: 'mock/json',
        toType: 'dir',
    },
    {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/*.jsp',
        toType: 'file',
        toType: 'dir',
    }, {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/jsp',
        to: 'jsp/',
        
    },
    {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor',
        to: 'vendor/',
        
    },
    {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/codemirror',
        to: 'vendor/codemirror',
        
    },
    {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/diff_match_patch',
        to: 'vendor/diff_match_patch',
        
    }, {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/scripts/vendor/next',
        to: 'vendor/next',
        
    }, {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/styles/',
        to: 'styles/'
    },  {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/bower_components/',
        to: 'bower_components/'
    }, {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/footerName.txt'
    }, {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/favicon.png'
    }, {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/favicon.ico'
    }, {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/404.html'
    }, {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/logoName.txt'
    }, {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/robots.txt'
    }, {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/favicon_original.png'
    }, {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/images/',
        to: 'images/'
    }, {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/styles/img/',
        to: 'styles/img'
    }, {
        from: 'node_modules/noVNC',
        to: 'vendor/noVNC',
    }, {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/scripts/novnc',
        to: 'novnc',
    },
    {
        from: 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css',
        to: 'styles/css/bootstrap/',
    },
    {
        from: 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js',
        to: 'bower_components/bootstrap/',
    },
    {
        from: 'node_modules/jquery/dist',
        to: 'bower_components/jquery/dist',
    },
    {
        from: 'src/main/webapp/app/scripts/jspScriptHandlers',
        to:"jspScriptHandlers"
    }]}
))
}
module.exports = config;
```

Out put of running webpack
ERROR]  [webpack.Progress] 10% building
[ERROR]  [webpack.Progress] 10% building 0/1 entries 0/0 dependencies 0/0 modules
[ERROR] (node:27426) ExperimentalWarning: queueMicrotask() is experimental.
[ERROR] (node:27426) [DEP_WEBPACK_RULE_LOADER_OPTIONS_STRING] DeprecationWarning: Using a string as loader options is deprecated (ruleSet[1].rules[2].use[0].options)
[ERROR]  [webpack.Progress] 10% building import loader ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
[ERROR]  [webpack.Progress] 10% building 0/1 entries 1/1 dependencies 0/1 modules

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and, surprisingly, I've found the `resolve.alias` option to be the culprit. Removing one particular item from there caused the build to succeed.

Comment: This was a big help for me.  Fixed my issue.